# Нормально ли такое поведение драйвера?

Tags: c, windows, драйвер

Я пишу драйвер под windows, который должен управлять дискреционной моделью доступа к объекту файловой системы(использую minifilter). Чтобы было откуда брать такую информацию, я открываю файл на чтение, пытался в разных функциях вызывать и отображать в  DebugView,но всё заканчивалось синим экраном смерти ОС. Методом тыка дошел до функции

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
```

Она является началом(как и main в обычном user-mode) моей программы.

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    NTSTATUS status;
    status = FltRegisterFilter(DriverObject, &FilterRegistration, &FilterHandle);
    if (NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        status=FltStartFiltering(FilterHandle);


        //now start the filter
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
        {
            //if fails - unregist 
            FltUnregisterFilter(FilterHandle);
        }
    }
    if (is_read == 0)
    {
        read_file();
        is_read = 1;
    }
    return status;
}
```

Я сделал проверку тут:`if (is_read == 0)`, чтобы точно вызывать лишь однажды функцию чтения. Но DebugView выдает это [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
То есть просто бесконечно вызывает функцию чтения. Как можно всё-таки вызвать файл в minifilter?

Это функция чтения из файла:

```
void read_file()
{
    KdPrint(("I AM HERE"));
    OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES obj_attributeR;
    NTSTATUS status;
    HANDLE filehandleR=NULL;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK IostatusblockR = {0};
    UNICODE_STRING filenameR = RTL_CONSTANT_STRING(L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\\conf.txt");
    InitializeObjectAttributes(&obj_attributeR, &filenameR, OBJ_CASE_INSENSITIVE | OBJ_KERNEL_HANDLE, NULL, NULL);
    status=ZwCreateFile(&filehandleR, GENERIC_READ, &obj_attributeR, &IostatusblockR, NULL, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, FILE_SHARE_READ, FILE_OPEN,
        FILE_NON_DIRECTORY_FILE | FILE_SYNCHRONOUS_IO_NONALERT,NULL,0);
    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
    {
        DbgPrint("openingfaild");
    }
    NTSTATUS status2;
    IO_STATUS_BLOCK iostatusblock = { 0 };
    PVOID buffer = NULL;
    ULONG length;
    LARGE_INTEGER offset = { 0 };
    length = 4096;
    buffer = ExAllocatePoolWithTag(NonPagedPool, length, tag);
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        KdPrint(("Error alloc"));
        return;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        length = 4096;
        status2 = ZwReadFile(filehandleR, NULL, NULL, NULL, &iostatusblock, buffer, length, &offset, NULL);
        KdPrint((buffer));
        if (!NT_SUCCESS(status2))
        {
            KdPrint((buffer));
            if (status == STATUS_END_OF_FILE)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        length = iostatusblock.Information;
        offset.QuadPart += length;
        //RtlInitUnicodeString(&uniName, L"\\Device\\HarddiskVolume2\\conf.txt");  // or L"\\SystemRoot\\example.txt"
    }
    ExFreePool(buffer);

}
```

Comment: volatile int is_read = 0; Так объявлен is_read, глобально

Comment: Вопрос решился, был невнимателен